# How To Check An Image Exists Or Not Through PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, image

I want to check an image hosted on another site/server if that exists or not at the time of code running. For this purpose I am using JavaScript that is working fine with my desire that I am sharing below. But some browsers doesn't support JavaScript or some users are using blocking extension to block JavaScript so at that time my code does run.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 var url = 'http://www.example.com/example.jpg';
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = url;
 img.onload = function()
 {
 alert('Image Is Available')
 }
 img.onerror = function()
 {
 alert('Image Is Not Available')
 }
</script>
```

So now I want to do the same as in above code but by pure PHP. I don't want to use `fsockopen`, `file_get_contents`, `curl`, `get_headers` option to hit and check the server. I only want to hit image and check that like above. For this purpose I used the below code but its not working. Its showing `Image Is Not Available` even I am able to open image directly in browser. I found this code over internet.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com/example.jpg';
if (@GetImageSize($url)) {
echo  "Image Is Available";
} else {
echo  "Image Is Not Available";
}
?>
```

So what the error is in this code? Can you mention and solve...???

**Update**: Please don't mention about image load time or size as I am hitting `favicon.ico` or other small size images on my target.

**Important Problem**: I check the above PHP code on another target and its working perfectly. But where I want to check the image is not working. Mine target didn't contain domain, Its an IP address like `hhtp://XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX/example.jpg`. So the code is correct but my target is not replying to any external codes hit. Its displaying the image when I open the link directly in the browser. SO my this question contain answer also. I will ask another question about my new problem.

Comment: Remove `@` before `getImageSize()`. Also : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-exists.php

Comment: Why don't you want to use `file_get_contents`? If you use that, you could simply check the magic variable `http_response_header` and it would contain an array of the headers, including an error code (302 or 404 or whatever). There's not going to be a perfect solution to this, because servers can respond to your request however they want, including not at all. The best you can do is look at the headers that the server returns. One useful header is the `Content-Type: image/jpeg`.

Comment: Is allow_url_fopen On? (see phpinfo())

Comment: @djidi Still not working after following your tip...

Comment: @PascalOckert Yes, Its On...

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius The reason why I am not using `fsockopen`, `file_get_contents`, `curl`, `get_headers` as they are not working on my target and now also `GetImageSize` is not working on my target but my mentioned JavaScript is working perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

The below code you pasted should work for you:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com/example.jpg';
if (@GetImageSize($url)) {
echo  "Image Is Available";
} else {
echo  "Image Is Not Available";
}
?>
```

Updated:
Ensure outgoing requests to port 80 (or whatever port you use for the outgoing http request to fetch the image) is not blocked on the server.

Note: Thanks Pascal Ockert for pointing out GetImageSize doesn't require GD. That was what I thought all this time and a quick Google shows that many others too. This is a classic example of "pass knowledge to learn more".

Comment: getimagesize() works without the GD library, see [Notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php#refsect1-function.getimagesize-notes).

Comment: The code that I shared and you also shared are Ok. Problem is that My targeted server is not replying any external PHP code hits. Its always give `Connection timed out` when I try to hit my server via `fsockopen`, `file_get_contents`, `curl`, `get_headers`, `GetImageSize`.

Comment: Check if port 80 on the server is open for outgoing requests.

Comment: @AkhtharParvez My port 80 is not open but other post is open so my target image URL is `http://XX.XX.XX.XX:XXXX/transparent.gif`

Answer (score 2):

Simplest of the answer is to use file_exists() function where param would be absolute file path, it returns true/false:

```
$isFileExists = file_exists($filePath);
```

Comment: I tried `if (file_exists('http://www.example.com/example.jpg')) {echo "The file exists";} else {echo "The file does not exist";}` but not working...

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$file = 'http://www.example.com/example.jpg';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $exists = false;
}
else {
    $exists = true;
}
echo $exists;
?>
```

Try above code.

Comment: I have edited the code and its functional. Good Luck :)

Comment: <?php
$file = 'http://www.example.com/example.jpg';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $exists = false;
}
else {
    $exists = true;
}
echo $exists;
?>

Comment: All answers are working now even my shared code is working so what to choose correct. Myself or all?

Comment: LOL...Nice question! Its totally upto you. Whichever you feel have helped you, can be marked.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

On second thought, I was wrong. Using a library like GD is the easiest and most reliable way to do this. I think you may just be using the function wrong (or not using GD?). The function [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) returns an *array* of elements describing the resource. The first two indices are the width and height. The doc says that if there is no image or multiple images or some other file, the width and height will be 0. So you could check that:

```
$img = getimagesize($url);
if($img[0] === 0)
   $imgFound = false;
```

Or you could check the third index (# 2), which is the filetype. To check this, you compare it against the GD [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/image.constants.php):

```
if($img[2] === IMG_JPG || $img[2] === IMG_JPEG)
    $imgFound = true;
```

Just make sure it's installed (check `phpInfo()`). Edit: The [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.image.php) however say that the GD extension doesn't need to be installed in order to use `getimagesize`, but the constants will only be available if you install it.

**Original answer**:

As I said in my comment, there's no perfect way to do this if you don't have control over the server hosting the image, since it can respond to your request however it likes (reject it, redirect, etc...). But you can use `file_get_contents` to get the file (which returns `false` on failure) and then check the headers using `$http_response_header` to see if it's an image. Here's an example script:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com/example.jpg';
// some servers will do a redirect to a valid image page, 
// so you don't want to reject a 302 necessarily.
$okCodes = array("200", "302");
$imgFound = false;
$pic = file_get_contents($url);
if($pic !== false) { 
    if(isset($http_response_header[0])) {
        $firstHeader = explode(" ", $http_response_header[0]);
        if(isset($firstHeader[1]) and in_array($firstHeader[1], $okCodes)) { 
            $count = count($http_response_header);
            for($j = 0; $j < $count; ++$j) {
                if(strpos($http_response_header[$j], "Content-Type: image/jpeg") !== false 
                    || strpos($http_response_header[$j], "Content-Type: image/jpg") !== false) {
                    $imgFound = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

// and if you're using ajax, echo it back to your app
if($imgFound) {
    echo json_encode(array("imgFound" => true));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array("imgFound" => false));
}
?>
```

One way to improve this script would be to find the LAST "HTTP/1.1 [ERROR_CODE] [ERROR_MESSAGE]" header in `$http_response_header` (which may contain multiple sets of headers - all merged into one array), which would allow you to see the headers for the file you're actually being served.

Comment: After using your code, I got `{"imgFound":false}` but I am able to see image in my browser...

Comment: That probably means that the response code was not 200 or 302 or that there was no "Content-Type: image/jpeg" line. The updated solution would work better for your purposes.

Comment: @Muhammad You mentioned "favicon.ico"? Does that mean the file you're trying to get is not a jpg or jpeg? It may not be supported by GD. If not, can you post the array that `getimagesize` returns? Does the function call work at all?

Comment: @I updated my question also and confirm that my shared code is ok but problem is same as old. My targeted server is not replying any external PHP code hits. Its always give `Connection timed out` when I try to hit my server via `fsockopen`, `file_get_contents`, `curl`, `get_headers`, `GetImageSize`. I am targeting a `JPG` image. I only mention `favicon.ico` to tell that I am hitting a small size image.